# ckeditor - not setting html data inside textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, cakephp, ckeditor

I am trying to use **ckeditor** with **cakephp** and I've written a *helper*. The problem is when I enter some line breaks or add checkboxes (or other html elements) with CKeditor, the editor crashes the next time I edit the content. Firefox returns the following error:

SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

and highlights `}).setData("<p>test</p>` from the section below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace('data[Template][body]',{
            toolbar: '',
            toolbarGroups: '',
            width: 950,
            height: 500
    }).setData("<p>test</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>test</p>");</script>
```

Here is the code in the cake helper:

```
$code = "CKEDITOR.replace('{$id}',{
            {$options['toolbar']},
            {$options['toolbarGroups']},
            width: {$options['width']},
            height: {$options['height']}
}).setData('" . trim($value). "');";

return $this->Javascript->codeBlock($code);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try this htmlspecialchar($value);

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary tried it, doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have linebreaks inside JavaScript string. You should output line breaks to HTML as "\n" so your HTML output would be like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace('data[Template][body]',{
        toolbar: '',
        toolbarGroups: '',
        width: 950,
        height: 500
}).setData("<p>test</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>test</p>");</script>
```

So inside your helper:

```
$out .= "}).setData('" .  str_replace("\n", '\n', $value). "');";
```

I've used single quotes so it will print out \n instead of line break;

Or you can use: `str_replace("\n", "\\n", $value)`